# reading file in C with fopen()

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program in C that needs to read lines from a file. I am using fopen() for that purpose currently.

This works fine with my program.

```
./myProgram /path/to/file
```

However, I am having trouble reading inputs like this:

```
./myProgram - <<END
This
is
some
nameless
file
END
```

So I am guessing `-` is the nameless file that has the contents between the 2 END's, but my program will given an error related to file not found in that case, which means that fopen() returned a null pointer.

I am wondering what is going on here?

Comment: `fopen` tries to open the file with name `-`, but doesn't find it, presumably. Parse options and if the filename is `-`, read from `stdin`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes I figured that out eventually! I will accept your answer if you post it below :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. According to `fopen`'s [man](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/), fopen requires a `const char*` to open the file. If you are just passing your argv into fopen, "This is some nameless file" is not a file path, and so `fopen` won't be able to find your file.

If you want to read from the stdin, you can use `fgets` or any other reading function that takes a `FILE *stream` argument, to which you can pass the `stdin` file stream.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured out a way to do it with fopen() as well.

Comment: I simply set the `FILE` pointer to `stdin` and read from there :)